# No 32-bit upgrade to 18.04LTS from 17.10 on Software Updater

Tags: 32-bit, 18.04, do-release-upgrade

Still looking for the **upgrade to 18.04LTS** option in my 17.10 32-bit Software Updater, but doesn't seem to be coming up, only 'normal' updates... thought it was 'out' by now... is there some lag time before it is available for upgrade to 17.10 users thru their software updater?

OR, is my Panasonic Toughbook laptop being boycotted due to minimum system requirements or something...?

Comment: I understood 'existing' 17.10 32-bit systems would be able to upgrade to a 32-bit 18.04... nothing about having to go to spin-offs...

Also, a guy working on assisting in developing 18.04 said I was essentially already 'using' 18.04 with 17.10 as updated all these days.

Comment: So - I just have to stay with 17.10 until support/updates put me out on the street, THEN worry about what to do - probably go back to my Vista64 office edition laptop again :-\

Comment: Did you try `do-release-upgrade -d`? The `-d` flag is needed until `18.04.1` version comes out.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix that timeline stated is only for LTS -> LTS upgrades; a week or two after release 17.10 -> 18.04 should become 'unlocked'

Comment: ran "do-release-upgrade -d" and get this:
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Upgrades to the development release are only 
available from the latest supported release.
...and I AM running 17.10, so?

Answer (score 3):

Canonical has finally removed 32-bit ubuntu from their support. So this means you can't get 32-bit 18.04. I believe 32-bit ubuntu will only continue in ubuntu flavours(lubuntu, edubuntu,etc). If you want to upgrade from 17.10, get a .iso file from one of the ubuntu flavours, either burn it to a cd, use startup disk creator to put it on a usb or mount the iso file via:

```
sudo mount *ubuntu.iso /mnt
```

You can either boot from it(if you put on a external medium) or find cdromupgrade. It should be in the root filesystem. Or you could try changing your repositorys to bionic instead of artful. You need to edit your sources.list file to do this though. It should be in /etc/apt/.

Comment: Are you sure that OP can't upgraded to 18.04? My understanding is that Canonical Ltd. has stopped providing 32-bit **iso images** since Ubuntu 17.10, but they still support upgrading to the next release.

Comment: ISO images are no longer supported, but i386 still exists in the repos, in *theory* you will still have 32bit support, but there's no ultimate ISO for it anymore.  Further, 17.10 -> 18.04 takes a few days for that to be made available (and by 'days' i mean 'business days', not days in general)

Comment: As far as I understood it: 18.04 64-bit still has the 32-bit compatibility. So you can  have a 18.04 64-bit system running 32-bit software.  I never saw an official source say a 32-bit could be upgraded to 18.04.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently "install to 18.04 via downloaded ISO image" (64-bit only) was released in April, but the "software upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04" (32-bit and 64-bit) will 'happen' maybe by end of May or sometime in June... it's just that 17.10 has been burning-up my processor and causing my video to crash (video memory shared with processor issue?). On MAY 25th 2018, the 'software updater' finally passed along the upgrade!!!!!!!!!! (Looks & runs just like 17.10...)

Comment: It is best to post a separate question on the **17.10** issue before it expires in July. Who knows you might be better off with 16.04 LTS or even 14.04 LTS which demand fewer CPU resources.

Comment: Posted the temp thing elsewhere - "dirt" then "undersized fan" only replies - both = N/A...
Anyway - May 23rd, 2018 and still no upgrade to 18.04 via 'software updater', so found this and tried:
Upgrading from Ubuntu 17.10 To upgrade on a desktop system:
    Press Alt+F2 and type  update-manager -c   into the command box.
    Update Manager should open up and tell you that Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is now available. (it popped-up, but sez I'm all updated... no upgrade available notice at all)

Comment: If not you can run  /usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release-gtk
    Click Upgrade and follow the on-screen instructions.
(Which I did, but nothing ever 'comes up'... the command box just goes away and nothing happens - bug?)

Comment: If I instead run /usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release-gtk in a terminal, I get:
~$ /usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release-gtk/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release-gtk:30: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk
WARNING:root:timeout reached, exiting