# Upgrade prompt for 18.04 LTS concerns

Tags: upgrade

I was prompted to upgrade to 18.04 LTS from 17.10 on 32 Bit DELL PC and went straight for it. The installation hung and couldn't boot the system thereafter. I have reinstalled 32 bit 17.10 after wiping the disk.  I have now had another prompt to install 18.04 LTS and deferred. How can I check this new upgrade is supported on my DELL 32-Bit PC ?

Comment: I have posted an answer to this question as an answer to a different question here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/5466/is-a-clean-install-better-than-upgrading/1035324#1035324, but I'm not sure that these two questions are exact duplicates even though I answered the other question. My answer isn't specific to Dell computers and I could answer either question, so I answered the more general question instead of answering this one.

Comment: Reverse question where 32-bit user on 17.10 isn't allowed to upgrade. There is an answer posted that 32-bit Ubuntu 18.04 comes out in July 2018: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028751/no-32-bit-upgrade-to-18-04lts-from-17-10-on-software-updater. Another Question here asking why there is a 32-bit install ISO when there isn't supposed to be one: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1014149/how-come-ubuntu-18-04-lts-has-a-32bit-iso-installer

Answer (score 0):

My Panasonic TUOGHBOOK is 32-bit with Ubuntu 17.10, and 'Software Updater' upgraded this morning to 18.04LTS without problems... took three hours and I was on pins and needles the whole time worried, but apparently worried for nothing. 18.04 looks and feels just like 17.10 though... Gonna do an image of the whole drive to a USB thumb drive via Ghost4Linux next! (add it to my 17.04 and 17.10 image collection)